# Unable to locate ADB - connecting to WearOS

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

There IS an adb.exe in my sdk path.

When I check [Project Structure > Project], there is no Project SDK heading, like in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLriw.png)

There is only ["Android Gradle Plugin Version" and "Gradle Version"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLHnS.png)

My watch has "ADB Debugging" and "Debug over Bluetooth" enabled.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Check you have Android SDK set in preferences

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I do indeed have it set :(
I have Android API 32 and Android 9.0 (Pie) installed and ticked.
Could it be to do with the version? I saw a tutorial for WearOS that said "Use the SDK manager to confirm that you have the latest version of the Android platform that supports Wear OS, Android 9 (API level 28)." Does this mean I shouldn't have Android API 32 ticked too? That's the onyl one that says API. Those are the only two ticked, except Android 12. (S) which isn't ticked but says "Partially installed"?
I also have Android Sdk Platform - Tools.

Comment: I'd usually use API 28 and 30 for Wear. Make sure you see "Wear OS 3 - Preview Intel x86 Atom System Image" (or ARM) installed if you click "Show Package Details" in the SDK Manager.